# String contains x amount of numbers and text

Tags: php, string, if-statement

I would like to check in php if a string contains 4 numbers plus a space and then text.

Something like this: `1234 asdf`

```
If there are more or less then 4 numbers => false  
If there is no text after the numbers => false
```

*How can I do this the proper way?*

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php  Perform a regular expression match

Comment: Can you do that in *any* way? As a newbie you should learn how to implement something that works, not something that looks nice.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

```
$text = '1234 dss';
$returnValue = preg_match('/^[0-9]{4} [a-zA-Z]{1,}$/', $text, $matches);
```

You can play with it here: https://www.functions-online.com/preg_match.html